# Permission Denied error while sending mail using Python smtplib

Tags: python, smtp, sendmail, smtplib

I am trying to send mail using Python 3.2. My code is as follows:

```
#from email import Encoders
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.utils import COMMASPACE, formatdate
import os
import smtplib
from base64 import encode
from email import encoders

def sendMail(to, subject, text, files=[],server="smtp.mydomain.com"):
    assert type(to)==list
    assert type(files)==list
    fro = "From <myemail@mydomain.com>"

    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['From'] = fro
    msg['To'] = COMMASPACE.join(to)
    msg['Date'] = formatdate(localtime=True)
    msg['Subject'] = subject

    msg.attach( MIMEText(text) )

    for file in files:
        part = MIMEBase('application', "octet-stream")
        part.set_payload( open(file,"rb").read() )
        encoders.encode_base64(part)
        part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="%s"'
                       % os.path.basename(file))
        msg.attach(part)

    smtp = smtplib.SMTP_SSL(server, 465)
    smtp.ehlo()
    smtp.set_debuglevel(1)
    smtp.ehlo()
    smtp.login("myemail@mydomain.com", "mypassword")
    smtp.ehlo()
    smtp.sendmail(fro, to, msg.as_string() )
    smtp.close()
    print("Email send successfully.")

sendMail(
        ["recipient"],
        "hello","cheers",
        []
    )
```

It gives me following error:

```
raise SMTPSenderRefused(code, resp, from_addr)
smtplib.SMTPSenderRefused: (501, b'5.7.1 <myemail@mydomain.com>... Permission denied', 'myemail@mydomain.com')
```

Does anybody know how to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What statement raises the exception?

Comment: @codeape: as seen in the stack trace line 27 seems to be raising the error. The code at line 27 is `mailServer.ehlo()`

Answer (score 1):

As the error says: you need to call the `connect` method on the `smtplib.SMTP_SSL` instance before you try to use it. `smtplib.SMTP_SSL` does not automatically connect (and neither does `smtplib.SMTP`.)

Comment: @Thomas: How should I call the connect() method? Can you please help me with a couple of lines of codes by refering to the code which I have pasted in the question.

Comment: @Thomas: adding the line `mailServer.connect()` after `mailServer = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.mydomain.net', 465)` gives me a new error which is `socket.error: [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it`...

Comment: @Thomas: Do you have any idea why am I getting this error. Can you please help me with a solution or guide me in a right direction... thanks in advance.

Comment: Check that the server is listening on port 465: telnet servername 465. Can you ping the server?

Comment: When i issue the command `telnet smtp.mydomain.net 465`, it show a blank screen... does it mean that it is listening (since I didn't end up with an error)

Comment: Try connecting to the specific address: `mailServer.connect('smtp.mydomain.net', 465)`

Comment: trying to connect using `mailServer.connect("smtp.mydomain.net", 465)` again gives the same `please run connect() first ` error... :-)

Comment: Sounds like the server keeps disconnecting then.